# Is const keyword mandatory while declaring"constexpr char*" string?

Tags: c++11, constants, c++17, constexpr

The project that I have just started working on has many instances of following,

```
constexpr const char* str = "Some Character(s)";
```

I wanted to understand, is the "const" keyword in above statement not redundant, as constexpr is implicitly constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mandatory because it won't compile if you remove it. This code:

```
constexpr char *str = "Some Character(s)";
```

Produces the following error on x64 GCC 11.2 ([link](https://godbolt.org/z/EbqWGoMbh)):

```
error: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
    1 | constexpr char *str = "Some Character(s)";
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The implied `const` is for the pointer itself so a redundant `const` would actually be this:

```
constexpr const char *const str = "Some Character(s)";
//                    ^~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

`const` and `constexpr` has diferent behaivours, as both has the same prefix, you may think that they are the same, but `constexpr` means that an atribute (or function, or whatever) will be done in compile time, and `const` means that that atribute won't be modified (it is an inmutable value, you can modify it, but thats undefined behaivour), but maybe can't be evaluated at compile time.

Also, in that particular case, you can't create an `char *`from an string literal since `-std=c++17`

Comment: `constexpr` implies `const`. In the OP declaration `constexpr` applies to the pointer, while the `const` applies to the pointee.